# Facebook how to send request that will link to download the application?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android and i want to sent request to friends to download my application.

Is it possible - through native methods or through graph api requests - to send a notification to the user that when it's clicked the user will be redirected to the Google Play store ?

For now i'm using FriendPickerFragment to show the users and pick them, and i want to send the request afterward.

Comment: i am finding the same. :)